# Html.Action not working with Route Attribute (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I been scratching my head trying to figure out on this issue.

I did a test where I have a TestController and it has a GetPartialView Action

```
public class TestController: Controller
{
     public IActionResult GetPartialView()
     {
         //do something to get data
         return PartialView("~/Views/test/_partialview.cshtml",null);
     }
}
```

So it works with the following code below

```
Html.Action("GetPartialView", "Test")
```

However it does not work if I put put Route attribute to my controller.

```
[Route("Test")]
public class TestController: Controller
```

It returns me this error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: actionDescriptor"

Anyone know how to make it work with Route Attribute. I can't seem to find any solution to this.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you rename the folder the view is located in to 'Test'? I'm not sure if it's case sensitive. If the view is in a folder called 'Test', can you not simply do `return PartialView("_partialview");`?

Comment: asp.net core has remove the Html.Action().How did you use this component?